# Javascript : Reference to a global variable getting lost when a popup is opened

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I am trying to communicate to a websocket server through a javascript web client. Here in my index.html, i have this code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        websocketClient = null
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jWebSocket.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ServerPlugin.js"></script>
```

and my main.js has these 2 functions (among others) :

```
function tempPopup() 
{

      var popupHeight = screen.height / 10 * 9;
      var popupWidth  = screen.width / 3;
      popup = window.open('popup.html', 'name-place', 'height='+popupHeight + ',width='+ popupWidth);
      popup.moveTo(screen.width / 2 - popupWidth/2, screen.height/2 - popupHeight/2);
      popup.focus();  
      websocketClient.sendResponse(400);
}

function transferReqToMain(quote) 
{
      alert("Request Transferred");
      websocketClient.sendResponse(400);
}
```

then my popup.html has these declarations :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jWebSocket.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ServerPlugin.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popupInit.js"></script>
```

and finally there is a function in popupInit.js that executes this way :

```
function sendOkResponse() 
{
    alert("Transferring Request");
    transferReqToMain(400);
};
```

Now when i press a button in index.html which is supposed to start a popup (function tempPopup()), the code of websoocket.sendResponse() gets executed just fine (I have an alert in the sendresponse function to tell me this)  and a new popup also starts. But in the popup if i click the button which launches sendOkResponse(), First i get the print "transferring Request", then i get the print "Request Transferred" (which mean transferReqToMain() is in execution) but after that my call to websocketClient.sendResponse() fails.

Can anyone point me to what i might be doing wrong here.